# How to prevent XML External Entity attack with JDK6

Tags: java, security, static-code-analysis, xxe

My application uses JDK6. I have to fix the XXE vulnerability in my code, able to find solution as below. But the below code works only with JDK7. I have a limitation to fix this without upgrading to JDK7. The code I found as fix is

`TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");`

So far I tried to use the following code. But it did not fix the issue.

`TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); tf.setAttribute(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);`

Comment: Have you found any workaround? i am facing similar issue.. i am on java8 but `treansformerFactoryImpl` is injected from `xalan` jar which does not support `ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD`